# responsive img in firefox with a max-width container

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design

Need a responsive img inside a container with a max-width.

HTML:

```html
<div class="center-content">
    <img src="assets/test-slider.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
/*center-content*/
.center-content{
    position:relative;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;}


/*img-fix*/
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This works fine in -webkit but not in firefox...

Any help would be appreciated.

/*EDIT*/

http://jsfiddle.net/WKHHR/

Check the difference between Firefox & Chrome

Comment: any demo or fiddle of your code will be appreciate.

Comment: Please explain what is not working about it.

Comment: When resizing browser-width to under the 1200px the img stay's in its original size. While in Chrome and Safarie it changes size according to the browser with.

Comment: It works fine for me in Firefox, using v24.0a1.

Comment: i see... works in fiddle for me to.. STUPID.. must be somthing to do with @media i think..

Comment: Could you also give the versions of the browsers you are using? Im checking on chrome 23, FF 16 and opera 12 and they all render the same way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the CSS for your image is wrong instead of

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

put

```
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is because you always want the image width to be 100% of it's parent div.

Comment: Its always the thing that are simple... Working to long on the same code i think, THNX!

Comment: this also worked for me when embedding images in Zurb Foundation. On firefox they wern't resizing and thus breaking out of their columns.

Comment: this may work, but it's not a universal answer. `max-width` is not the same as `width`. In the general case, setting width to 100% is wrong - this shouldn't be set globally, and should only be set on images where you explicitly require it. Setting max-width to 100% globally, on the other hand, is a good default.